# How can I upload media with MiniDLNA media server or are there any DLNA servers that allow this?

Tags: dlna, upload, upnp, minidlna

I have been enjoying the MiniDLNA server on my Ubuntu box for a while now.  It works very well with XBox and a cheap Magnavox Blue-ray player that I bought.

Now I am wanting to start uploading media to my server but when I try my devices all come back with the error that uploading is not supported.  Does anyone know of a DLNA server that works with mkv, mp4, avi and supports upload to the server?

Answer (score 0):

The GNOME default DLNA server [**Rygel**](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/rygel) [image: Install rygel] claims to be able to support file upload when the following was set to `true` in `/etc/rygel.conf`

```
# Allow upload of media files?
allow-upload=true
```

You also will have to define the upload directories in case you are not using the default directories.

```
# Where music files should be saved if allow-upload is true
# Defaults to @MUSIC@, the standard music folder (typically ${HOME}/Music).
music-upload-folder=@MUSIC@
```

We have no experience how well Rygel operates with the XBox. On our systems here (Android, SmartTV) MiniDLNA is much more stable than Rygel but we do have to upload media to the server via traditional paths.

Also see:

- [Rygel project page](https://live.gnome.org/Rygel)

Comment: but how to connect to upload files?